# Amazon MWS API - How do i get detailpageurl, product reviews, totalresult count

Tags: amazon-mws

I have integrated the Amazon MWS api.For searching matching products from amazon i have used ListMatchingProducts as operation. I got the response as XML but in XML Some of the information isn't provided by the Amazon MWS API is there any other way to get it? The following information is not able to get from api response xml.

1. How do we get more pages of results beyond the first page? Right now we only get the first.
2. We cannot find big images for products, only getting small images
3. We cannot find the detailpageurl for products.
4. Where do we get the description? The only thing we are able to pull right now is the product "Features" but no description.
5. How do you search by Amazon nodes? All we see is search by keywords, but we use nodes all the time in the old Amazon PA-API.

Answer (score 0):

For larger images, you can substitute out the numbers following "_SL" in the image name for the desired width.  ie: *SL160*.jpg becomes *SL400*.jpg  for a 400px width image.

A quick version of the detail page URL can be constructed by appending the ASIN to  http://www.amazon.com/dp/

I don't think the other functionality that you desired is available through the MWS Products API.